# Compiler can't find wx.h when building with CodeLite?

Tags: c++, mingw, wxwidgets, codelite

1. I downloaded the wxWidgets source.
2. Compiled wxWidgets using MinGW.
3. Created a CodeLite project under the GUI category with the executable (wxWidgets enabled) type.
4. In project settings > Compiler > Include Paths, I added the line "C:\Libraries\wxWidgets-3.2.4\include".
5. In project settings > Linker > Libraries Search Path, I added the line "C:\Libraries\wxWidgets-3.2.4\lib\gcc_dll".
6. In project settings > Linker > Libraries, I added the line "libwxmsw32u_core;libwxbase32u".
7. Cleaned the project.

However, when building, this error happens:

```
C:/Users/Name/Workspaces/BegginerProjects/GUITest.cpp:1:10 fatal error: wx/wx.h: No such file or directory.
```

I don't know what else to do. Any help?

I am on windows btw.

Comment: Does the file: `C:\Libraries\wxWidgets-3.2.4\include\wx\wx.h` exist?

Comment: ***Compiled wxWidgets using MinGW.*** I recommend switching to use msys2 to install MinGW and use `pacman` to install wxWidgets (and any other open source libraries). msys2 has a large collection of packages available in its repository.

Comment: @drescherjm \wx\wx.h does exist
and I see, I didn't know about that, I will take a look on msys2! Thanks a lot.

Comment: If that exact path to the header file exists for some reason step #4 is not working or not active or something like that.